# Datatables pagination links not styled with bootstrap5 in a Laravel application not working after running npm run build

Tags: javascript, laravel, datatables, bootstrap-5, vite

I'm building with datatables.js, vite as the bundler, Laravel and vanilla JavaScript. Been working in development with npm run dev and everything was fine so I didn't notice earlier. Now after running npm run build, my datatable previous and next links have lost their style. When I run npm run dev it works fine but when I build with npm run build, the styles are lost again.
[image]
I have the useBootstrapFive function in the boot method of the AppServiceProvider.

```
public function boot(): void
    {
        JsonResource::withoutWrapping();
        Paginator::useBootstrapFive();
    }
```

I have deleted node modules and reinstalled npm packages afresh.

this is how I am loading my scss bootstrap files in my app.scss file

```
@import "./variables.scss";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css";
@import "../../node_modules/datatables.net-bs5/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.css";
```

these are the imports into my app.js file

```
import "../css/app.scss";
import "bootstrap";
import "./bootstrap";
import "../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js";
import "../../node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.mjs";
import "../../node_modules/datatables.net-bs5/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.mjs";
import 'datatables.net-plugins/api/sum().mjs';
import 'datatables.net-fixedheader-bs5';
import 'datatables.net-buttons-bs5';
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.mjs';
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.mjs';
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.mjs';
import 'datatables.net-fixedcolumns-bs5';
import 'datatables.net-select-bs5';
import 'datatables.net-staterestore-bs5';
```